# MySQL MEMORY table has high Lock Wait Ratio

Tags: mysql, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mysql Memory table getting many locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/mysql-memory-table-getting-many-locks)

on my site I log every pageview (date,ip,referrer,page,etc) in a simple mysql table.

This table gets very little selects (3 per minute), but a lot of inserts. (about 100 per second)

Today I changed this table from an InnoDB table to a MEMORY table, this made sense to me to prevent unnecessary hard disk IO. I also prune this table once per minute, to make sure it never get's too big.

--

Performance wise, things are running fine. But I noticed that while running tuning-primer, that my Current Lock Wait ratio is quite high.

```
Current Lock Wait ratio = 1 : 561
```

*My question:* Should I worry about this Lock Wait Ratio? And is there something I can change in my my.cnf to improve things so that the lock wait ratio isn't so high?

Comment: Removing a bottleneck (Disk I/O) makes the next bottleneck (Lock wait ratio) more appearant.

Comment: This is a duplicate of `MySQL Memory table getting many locks`