# MySQL: sysbench test - InnoDB vs Memory tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory

I've done some tests in order to investigate performance issue on the new HP Gen8 server `(Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz)`

I've created two tables, first one is using `InnoDB` storage engine and the second one is in `Memory` - heap table.

System details:

```
sysbench-0.4.12-5.el6.x86_64
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

**Prepare stage:**

InnoDB

```
# sysbench --db-driver=mysql --test=oltp --mysql-table-engine=innodb --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=sbtest1 prepare
```

Memory (heap)

```
# sysbench --db-driver=mysql --test=oltp --mysql-table-engine=heap --oltp-table-size=1000000 --mysql-db=sbtest2 prepare
```

**Testing stage:**

Sysbench – read only test – single table with 1 mln rows - data size 559MB (527MB data + 31MB indexes)

InnoDB

```
# sysbench --db-driver=mysql --test=oltp --mysql-table-engine=innodb --num-threads=128 --max-requests=100000 --oltp-read-only run
```

Total time: 16.3648s, TPS (transactions per second): 6111.40

Memory (heap)

```
# sysbench --db-driver=mysql --test=oltp --mysql-table-engine=heap --mysql-engine-trx=no --num-threads=128 --max-requests=100000 --oltp-read-only run
```

This test is running much longer and I had to stop it as the load on the server was very high - even if this is in memory table!?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have addressed InnoDB vs MEMORY before

- `Jan 21, 2012` : [Is InnoDB Engine up to speed against Memory Engine?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11099/is-innodb-engine-up-to-speed-against-memory-engine/11191#11191)
- `Jan 17, 2012` : [Mysql Memory table getting many locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/mysql-memory-table-getting-many-locks/10821#10821)

I also addressed the one headache MEMORY tables have: There is still disk I/O because of the `.frm` file (See my post [I am using the MEMORY storage engine but MySQL still writes to my disk...Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-the-memory-storage-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why/2876#2876)).

Also worth remembering is the fact that MEMORY tables do table-level locks.

You should just increase the InnoDB buffer pool and leave MEMORY tables behind

Comment: Thanks, changing index type to `BTREE` helped a lot.