# Why MySQL performs so poor on SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, query, myisam

I've installed MySQL server with many databases that use the InnoDB engine. With lots of procedures in each DB, `mysql`.`proc` table contains more than 250,000 rows and it becomes ultimately slow when I need to run a query like this one:

```
SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS WHERE db LIKE '%SomeDB%';
```

The above query takes more than 5 seconds to execure and tweaking MySQL configuration parameters such as `myisam_sort_buffer_size` or `key_buffer_size` (which where already large enough) made no difference. I've 256GB memory installed on my server and I don't think it is because of any kind of memory shortage, maybe some misconfiguration that I have no Idea about it. Any hint?

Comment: @RickJames I do not fetch nor need this information, but seems that the new version of Connector/J does! (after I upgraded from Connector/J 5 to 8, I see that lots of lots of these statements are being called at tomcat startup that causes my application stuck at this stage). I use MySQL 5.7 community edition, I have many (+300) similar but distinct databases (all use InnoDB), each one with lots of functions and procedures.

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli No matter when the procedure is created and wheter it is used or not, result is almost the same. `mysql`.`proc` as well as all other tables in `mysql` db are MyISAM.

Comment: So it's not a metadata lock. Your query is slow because it cannot use an index. 1 Can you use LIKE 'dbname%' instead of LIKE '%dbname%'? 2 If so, do it, and then check if there is an index whose first column is db. If not, create an index on db.

Comment: If each database has the same functions, consider creating a separate database for holding all the common functions and procs.  Then use dbname.functionname syntax to access them.  (And set up suitable GRANTs for users.)

Answer (score 4):

The "meta" commands (`SHOW...`) are generally not designed for performance.  The presumption is that you rarely, if ever, need to run them.  And when you do, it is more of a "one-time" operation.

Please migrate from MyISAM to InnoDB.  (This will probably have no effect on the Question at hand, but is important for many other reasons.)

Before 8.0, the information for many of the `SHOW` commands was scattered around various files.  For example, each table had a `.frm` file containing, effectively, the `CREATE TABLE` information.  "File open" took time, leading to slowness.

8.0 moved all that info into InnoDB tables so, in theory, it should be straightforward to fetch all the data more efficiently.  However, the implementation seems to involve layers of `VIEWs` and inadequate indexing.

In any case, 250K of anything takes time.  I could have mentioned the leading wildcard (`%`) on the `LIKE` because it prevents the use of an index.  However, I am not convinced that there is a relevant index.

Comment: I remember MySQL 5.6 having issues with this. When I ran it, a ton of debug into would appear. So, I would do `SELECT db,name FROM mysql.proc` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE db.name\G`. I have long stopped using `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`

Comment: As I mentioned my DBs are already InnoDB, and actually I fell in trouble when I was upgrading from Connector/J 5 to 8 (which my app depends on for creating a connection pool in tomcat). For whatever reason, it sounds that this new version calls so many `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` at tomcat startup and causes app to literally hangs!

Comment: File a bug report.

Comment: That was only 5.6 I saw this. It goes EOL Feb 2021

Answer (score 3):

Please note that most of INFORMATION_SCHEMA is implemented as temporary memory tables (See my old post [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336))

When mysqld starts, information from `mysql.proc` is loaded into [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html).

When you use `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS`, the info is retrieved from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html).

Since temp tables will have `.frm`, Rick already mentioned accessing it would make some slowness. This my be due to I/O if mysqld checks `mysql.proc` and/or [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-routines-table.html).

See also

- [Mysql Memory table getting many locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/mysql-memory-table-getting-many-locks/10821#10821)
- [I am using the MEMORY storage engine but MySQL still writes to my disk...Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-the-memory-storage-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why/2876#2876)

So, basically, you are at the mercy of how mysqld checks for stored procedures to see it is up-to-date in memory.