# What is the fastest way to insert data into MySQL memory table?

Tags: mysql, insert, memory, mysql-5.7

I need to insert 10M+ records into a MySQL memory table.

A naive approach was to pipe records using shell, e.g.

```
$ tail -10 ~/Desktop/test.sql
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (5, 6);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (6, 7);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (6, 7);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (2, 3);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (3, 4);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (4, 5);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (5, 6);
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES (6, 7);
$ mysql -u root -proot test < ~/Desktop/test.sql
```

The table itself is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `a` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `b` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In essence, the question is what are some lower level ways of inserting data to MySQL?

Comment: If you have your data in some other format than insert statements, you might use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) which is supposed to be optimized for batch loads.

Comment: Don't forget to set `max_heap_table_size` before creating the table.

Answer (score 2):

You need to batch the inserts. This is done by means of extended inserts.

In your question, you can take the row and make them a single insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`a`, `b`) VALUES
(4, 5),(5, 6),(6, 7),(6, 7),(1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 4),(4, 5),(5, 6),(6, 7);
```

Why do it this way ?

When you insert into a MEMORY table, there is still some mild disk I/O to check the table's existence by hitting the table `.frm` file. I wrote about this 5 years ago ([I am using the MEMORY storage engine but MySQL still writes to my disk...Why?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/i-am-using-the-memory-storage-engine-but-mysql-still-writes-to-my-disk-why/2876#2876))

Your question's example does 10 inserts. That's 10 disk reads to the `.frm` file and 10 full table locks ([the lock granularity for the MEMORY storage engine is a full table lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/memory-storage-engine.html)).

Changing it into a single extended insert, the `.frm` is read only once and the table locked once.

## SUGGESTION

In your case, if test.sql has 10 million rows, there will 10 million tables locks and 10 million access of the `.frm` file.

You should setup test.sql to batch like 10,000 rows in a single insert. Don't worry, mysqldumps create extended insert like this all the time.

That way, you will have 1000 inserts instead of 10,000,000.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!